# Change Default Windows Sound With Powershell

Tags: powershell, audio

I would like to find a way to change the windows default sound with powershell.

In vbs it is written like this:

```
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\.Default\.Current\","c:\windows\media\horn.wav","REG_SZ"
```

I tried invoking the command but did not know the correct way to do it.

Comment: Have a look at [Set-ItemProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty)

Answer (score 3):

There are (at at least) two pretty simple ways to do this in PowerShell. The first is to use the WShell from within PowerShell (at least in Windows PowerShell 5.1 - unsure about Core):

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$wshell.RegWrite("HKCU\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\.Default\.Current\","c:\windows\media\horn.wav","REG_SZ")
```

The second is a more built-in way using PowerShell's [`Set-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet - which should work in Core versions.

```
$SetItemProperty = @{
    Path         = "HKCU:\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\.Default\.Current\"
    Name         = "(default)"
    Value        = "c:\windows\media\horn.wav"
}
Set-ItemPoperty @SetItemProperty
```

(Note: using the hashtable variable with the `@` symbol instead of the common `$` symbol is called [`Splatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1); it's effectively just matching up parameter names to values so I don't have to write out a really (horizontally) long command.)

Answer (score 2):

Powershell does not have a native cmdlets for that, beside you would have to use `C#` to get that functionality in powershell.

Luckily, someone did the hardwork and put that in to a module, check the following repo :
https://github.com/frgnca/AudioDeviceCmdlets

There are detailed instructions on how to install the module, once you done that you can see all devices

```
Get-AudioDevice -List


Index   : 1
Default : True
Type    : Playback
Name    : Speakers (2- Jabra EVOLVE LINK)
ID      : {0.0.0.00000000}.{8c58263c-e6a0-4c7b-8e51-5231f04cbcb9}
Device  : CoreAudioApi.MMDevice
```

From there you can see the current `Default` device and change it however you like.